# How to prevent a Pull Request Merge to break the build?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo, git-flow

Currently working on a gitflow branching strategy on git, bamboo and bitbucket.

I am new to gitflow (coming from github flow) so bare with me.

At the moment, I've set it up in a way that my builds are triggered for each feature branch independently (so each feature branch commit will trigger a build for that branch). When the feature is ready, I would raise a PR and once approved, it will be merged into develop branch.

I am trying to find a way to make sure the merge into develop branch won't break the build of develop branch.

I could ask developers or the person in charge of merging the PR to manually merge DEV into the feature branch PR and have the build pass but, isn't there a better way of doing this?

What have you implemented or have seen before that would make more sense than this?

Summarising my question, how can I trigger a build before merging the PR and only merge if the build is green?

Comment: Write or find a merge check that automatically merges the MR to target branch and runs a build.

Comment: @fredrik so I've been thinking to 'write' a bamboo plugin to basically trigger a build of my feature branch using the 'branch merge' functionality provided by bamboo which basically will do the merge of the branges and build. If the build is green then allow merging otherwise it fails. It is just amusing that a simple requirement as such is not broadly documented or is it that the whole devops CI/CD is in reality an utopy and everyone is merging broken code?

Comment: It exists elsewhere, but not in bitbucket/bamboo. So most certainly "everyone" does not have this problem.

Comment: I don't see a conceptual difference regarding testing the build prior to merging a feature branch into `develop` in Git Flow vs `main` in GitHub Flow. Are you thinking there is a difference or was the fact that you moved from GitHub Flow to Git Flow just extra information?

Comment: @TTT yes it is just extra information as it wouldn't be related to the flow I am using. So you are correct.